# Magento edit content in $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()

Tags: magento

I am in the progress of editing a piece of text (correcting a spelling) under

```
app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\products_list.phtml
```

The function is called:

```
$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()
```

However, neither can I find anything inside code nor admin panel.  I just want to adjust some HTML text inside it, can any one please tell me where can I find these content?

I am not the original developer of this site, that's why I don't know where to find those text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is calling for the Category Description.  From the Administrators interface you will use the Catalog menu option (along the top) then Manage Categories.

Comment: No it is not there.  I checked that several times.

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing?  That is where you find the text for that function.

Comment: I am looking for the piece of text that I want to edit.
Now I found it.  You are right, it is under the place you mention, simply it is not in the same view.

Alberto, thank you for your help.  :D

Comment: No worries, I am glad ot help!